# How can I select only specific subelements in XQuery?

Tags: xml, xquery

Say I have elements `<country>`, and that those elements have all lots of subelements like `<name>`, `<population>`, `<cities>`, some of which have their own subelements. If I call

```
for $x in doc("myfile.xml")/world
return <country> { $c/country } </country>
```

Then I'll get all of those countries, with all of their subelements, their subelements, and so on. However, say I just want to select all of the cities in the country, but including the subelements of those cities. How can I do this?

Comment: What language are you using?  How to parse and search your file is going to depend on the language.

Comment: There's an XQuery sample in the question, and the `xquery` tag has been applied as well.

Answer (score 2):

You use XPath expressions to select elements in XQuery.

- `$x/country/*` selects all child elements of country.
- `$x/country/cities` selects only the `<cities/>` child elements
- `$x/country/(name|population|cities)` selects the specified child elements (`|` is the union operator, and parenthesis create a sequence)